# Deleting multiple rows PHP Ajax not work correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using php codeigniter framework.

Now  I want to delete my table row item selection multiple by checkbox.

after selection multiple item when click delete button the a ajax request call controller function then delete process work.

I am trying but not work.

```
$('#delete_multiple').click(function(){
     id=new Array()
     id = $('#deletem #selector').val();
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: ""+baseUrl+"deletes/"+id,
               success: function(msg) {

                if(msg === "success" )
                {
                    showPagination();
                }
                else if(msg === "error" )
                {
                    $('#delete-server-error').show('slow').append("<p>Server is little bit busy. Please try few minute later.</p>");
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#delete-server-error').show('slow').append(msg);
                }

               }
          });

    });
```

My form is

```
<form method="post" id="deletem"  action="" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete_multiple" >Delete</button>

<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
</form>
```

My controller code

```
function deletes($id)
{
    if($id != 0)
    {
        if($this->retailer_model->deletes($id))
            echo "success";
        else
            echo "error";
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('retailer');
    }

}
```

My model code

```
function deletes($id)
{

    return $status1 = $this->db->delete('image', array('id' => $id));

}
```

when I click delete button then nothing deleted .Using firebug I see noting value pass to controller.

Comment: logging `$('#deletem #selector').val();`  gives any value? and also what is `id=new Array()` doing in that code block? doesnt make any sense. No `var` no semicolon at the end!!.

Answer (score 1):

you can serialize a form and you will get all checked checkboxes

```
url: ""+baseUrl+"deletes",
data:$('#deletem').serialize(),
```

No need of these lines

```
id=new Array()
id = $('#deletem #selector').val();
```

and in controller do this

```
foreach ($_POST['selector'] as $id) 
{
  $this->retailer_model->deletes($id)
}
```

Comment: just put this in controller if($this->retailer_model->deletes($_POST['selector'])){echo "success";}else{ echo "error";} and replace this lines in model $this->db->where_in('id', $id);return $status1 = $this->db->delete('image');

Answer (score 0):

Your id wont return a value as you are not targeting the check boxes.

Try this....

```
var ids = $('input[name="selector[]"]').val();
```

Also if you are sending an array you will need to send some data rather than pass it through the URL.

For example:

```
url: ""+baseUrl+"deletes",
data: {ids: ids},
```

Also in your PHP if you are sending multiple ids you will need to loop through then and call the deletes method on each iteration.

For example:

```
foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
    $this->retailer_model->deletes($id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using name selector, not id.

```
<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Use this:

```
id = $('#deletem input[name="selector"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting the value of of id in your controller properly
first you send data like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('your_controller/your_method'); ?>",
            data: {"id": id},
```

then in your controller get it like

```
$_POST['id']'

$this->retailer_model->deletes($_POST['id'])
and in your model 
function deletes()
{
and print_r($id);
/*check if values are in array
then*/ 
foreach ($id as $idd){
    return $status1 = $this->db->delete('image', array('id' => $idd));
}
}
and bingo
```